# Significance of DCC GARCH correlations

Tags: correlation, statistical-significance, garch

Is there a way to check whether correlations extracted from DCC GARCH model are significant or not?

Comment: Significant in which sense? Statistically significantly different from zero?

Comment: Yes, using p-values? The sign of correlation estimates from DCC GARCH for two time series is opposite of what I get from Pearson’s. The results of Pearson’s are significant at 5% level.

Comment: Any help? From what I read more on DCC I understand that if I look at p-values of alpha1 and beta1 then together if it less than 0.05 then the model fits. Am I correct? If so then if out of 10 series, 7 have p-values lower then 0.05 while the remaining 3 have higher p-values, then can I say that the correlations between those 7 series is significant?

Comment: Also, dcca is 1.00 while dccb is 0.00, what does this signify?

Comment: I think looking at the significance of the coefficients in the cond. correlation equation will not give an answer to the question of whether the correlation is significantly different from zero. I like your question (+1 already), but I do not have an answer right now. I will keep thinking in my free time and see if I can come up with anything.

Comment: Thanks @RichardHardy for considering the question. What prompted me was the difference in the correlation estimates using the two methods. For example, Pearson gives:  
AUS-CAN 0.257, AUS-USA 0.253, AUS-AUT 0.322, AUS-BEL 0.359   while DCC gives:  AUS-CAN -0.036, AUS-USA -0.138, AUS-AUT -0.067, AUS-BEL -0.106  If the coefficients in the cond. correlation equation are not significant then is it that the model is not a good fit to my data and as a result I am obtaining such a different correlation estimate using DCC?

Comment: The correlation you are obtaining is between series that are adjusted for conditional heteroskedasticity, so no wonder it is different from raw correlation. This is independent of whether the coefficients in the DCC equation are significant. These coefficients only concern variation over time, not the overall magnitude. Try calculating unconditional correlation between standardized residuals from GARCH models; you should get something like the output from DCC.

Comment: @RichardHardy thanks for the explanation. I have to justify this outcome to an exam panel next week; I’m in a better position to handle this question now. I tried estimating unconditional correlations between standardised residuals as per your suggestion: the correlation coefficients are in same direction as what I got from DCC but even lower. I’ll take this forward to the exam panel for now. Thanks again.

Comment: If you come back in a couple of days, I might have composed an answer out of the comments (do not have the time for it right now). Good luck with the examiners!

Comment: @RichardHardy I’ll wait for when you have more time. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @RichardHardy sorry to bother you on this again but in regards to our previous discussion on why correlations from DCC is different. I understand that rationale but when I tried plotting time-varying correlations, I am not sure what I get is right.  I have uploaded some plots here https://drive.google.com/open?id=1C9xbqnb70LQd1jQiZHkYmK3GX_T6tYx3 If you look at the y-axis, the correlations vary but only after several decimal points! Does this even mean anything? Or chances is that there is something wrong with my code or data?

Comment: I would like to help you, but I am quite busy at work and do not have the energy to dig deeper into your problem. I am sorry. If only there were more hours in a day!..

Comment: Just to update you.. my exam panel were happy with the explanation I gave for difference in correlation estimates that I obtained using both models. Thanks for your timely and kind assistance!! Now I just have to write it up very well in my thesis chapter.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know! I am glad I could contribute!